# parsing through an android object

Tags: php, android

how do I properly store these values into my code in android?

```
   {
    "propoints": "25",
    "preflocation": "Adele H. Stamp Student Union"
    }
```

my PHP creates an array like this

$response = array("propoints" => "", "preflocation" => "");

stores the values and returns using json_encode

I dont know how to store the hashs returned and store into my variables

```
JSONArray feedArr = new JSONArray(ActionEngine.jsonParser.getJSONString());

            ProcityActivity.propoints = (String) feedArr.get(0);
            ProcityActivity.preflocation = (String) feedArr.get(1);

            Toast.makeText(act.getApplicationContext(),
                    ActionEngine.jsonParser.getJSONString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "is having some trouble" ?

Comment: I don't know how to properly get back the json_encode hash and store its values into my variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are constructors for the JSONObject (like the one you have as an example) that take as a parameters the data from the internet (Streams or Strings) then you can map it with Gson directly to your objects

( more on that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSON )

or you can use the methods to map out the values as described at: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the JSON snippet at the beginning isn't a JSONArray but a JSONObject.

Secondly, storing values through static variables isn't the best idea. 
Thirdly, that toast indicates you are storing some instance of activity in the object that holds the java snippet. Pass a context.